# Whats the best way to force Streams.zip to iterate over each element (using Guava, Java)

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream, guava

I am trying to use Streams.zip to create a map. I don't care about the stream returned result, I just need the lambda to execute for each element. Here is my code

```
String x[] = {"a", "b"};
String y[] = {"c", "d"};

var data = new HashMap<String, String>();

var myStream = Streams.zip(Arrays.stream(x), Arrays.stream(y),
                (arg1, arg2) -> { data.put(arg1, arg2); return 0; };
var result = myStream.collect(Collectors.toList()); // ideally don't want this line
```

Without the collect( ) line I don't populate the map, so what's simplest way to do this, I tried count() instead of collect but this shortcuts the zip entirely.
Or is there a simpler one line solution without Streams.zip to populate a map from two lists?

Comment: Can you state the expected output? It would explain the problem more clearly

Comment: you can collect `toMap` then, but without a terminal operation, you wouldn't be able to actually execute the `put`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [`Streams#forEachPair`](https://guava.dev/releases/29.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Streams.html#forEachPair-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.stream.Stream-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) instead:

```
String x[] = {"a", "b"};
String y[] = {"c", "d"};

var data = new HashMap<String, String>();

Streams.forEachPair(Arrays.stream(x), Arrays.stream(y), data::put);

System.out.println(data); // {a=c, b=d}
```

Obviously if you don't need to control HashMap, you can just collect:

```
String x[] = {"a", "b"};
String y[] = {"c", "d"};

var result = Streams.zip(Arrays.stream(x), Arrays.stream(y), Maps::immutableEntry)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

System.out.println(result); // {a=c, b=d}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach:

```java
String[] keys = {"k1", "k2"};
String[] values = {"v1", "v2"};
Map<String, String> result = IntStream.range(0, keys.length).boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> keys[i], i -> values[i]));
```

This has the advantage of being side-effect free while not having to create map entries manually before merging them, all handled by the collector itself.